# SSL for multiple domains in single website

Tags: ssl, iis-8

Is it at all possible to install multiple SSL certificates for each domain on the same website?

I've got the following setup running via IIS.

1. www.domain1.com  > IP (xx.xxx.xx.01) Has SLL already installed
2. www.domain2.com  > IP (xx.xxx.xx.02) **I want to install SSL for this domain**
   subdomain1.domain2.com > IP (xx.xxx.xx.02)
   subdomain2.domain2.com > > IP (xx.xxx.xx.02)

All domains have to point to the same website as that is how the solution is meant to work. We are using nopCommerce 3.5 and have a multi store setup. So that's why it's not an option to have separate websites for each domain.

Comment: Why cannot you try SNI? https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Comment: I'm going to give it a try tonight